# how can I get, fetched data from neo4j?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, neo4j, fetch

I was trying to fetch data from neo4j database.
Here is my function for getting data from database which I found on their official website and have modified it little bit:

```
function receiveDataFromDB() {
 var neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");
 var driver = neo4j.driver(
   "neo4j://localhost",
   neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "something")
 );

 console.log(driver);
 var session = driver.session({
   database: "neo4j",
   defaultAccessMode: neo4j.session.READ,
 });

 session.run(`match (n) return n`).subscribe({
   onKeys: (keys) => {
     console.log(keys);
   },
   onNext: (record) => {
     console.log(record.get("n"));
   },
   onCompleted: () => {
     session.close(); // returns a Promise
   },
   onError: (error) => {
     console.log(error);
   },
 });
}
```

So this function only console.log-s it:

[image]

but I want it to use outside the function. I've tried returning `return record.get("n")` inside `onNext` but got errors instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the try-catch equivalent of your query, like this:

```
try { 
const result = session.run(`match (n) return n`);
} catch (error) {}
finally {
  session.close();
}
```

Or try setting your result in a variable, like this:

```
const result = [];
session.run(`match (n) return n`).subscribe({
   onKeys: (keys) => {
     console.log(keys);
   },
   onNext: (record) => {
     result.push(record.get("n"));
   },
   onCompleted: () => {
     session.close(); // returns a Promise
   },
   onError: (error) => {
     console.log(error);
   },
 });
```

Comment: and then how can I access certain node?

Comment: the `result` will be an array of nodes, you can loop over and get your desired node

Comment: yah but it's not, it does not even fetches data from db

Comment: try logging the error in catch block.

Comment: https://ibb.co/StPFVnr check this out